# How can I set cookie value with the char , and " in netty httpclient

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, webclient

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t87k.png)

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cookie value contains an invalid char: , at io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.CookieEncoder.validateCookie(CookieEncoder.java:48) at io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ClientCookieEncoder.encode(ClientCookieEncoder.java:217) at io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ClientCookieEncoder.encode(ClientCookieEncoder.java:86) at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.addCookie(HttpClientOperations.java:167) at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpRequest.lambda$applyCookies$4(ReactorClientHttpRequest.java:133) at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpRequest.lambda$applyCookies$5(ReactorClientHttpRequest.java:131) at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:647)`

I want to set the cookie like below：

it failed

Comment: cxt.getDownloader().getWebClient()
                .get()
                .uri("xxxxxxx", AvaiRequest.builder().build().toMap())
                .headers(this::setHeader)
                .cookie("STORAGE_PREFERENCES", "{'STRICTLY_NECESSARY':true,'PERFORMANCE':true,'FUNCTIONAL':true,'TARGETING':true,'SOCIAL_MEDIA':true,'PIXEL':true,'GANALYTICS':true,'__VERSION':2}")
                .exchangeToMono(resp -> {

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify or add code; code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead. A [mcve] would be helpful. See [ask].